# float values to time that includes nulls

Tags: python-3.x

I have columns with time as float values. the columns also have null values that I want to keep since by removing them deletes other dimensions I am interested  in in my table. because of the null values i am not able to transform the the values into strings before converting to timestamps.

I am using this code

```py
def Format_Hourmin(hours):
        if hours == 2400:
            hours = 0
        else:
            hours = "{0:04d}".format(int(hours))
            Hourmin = datetime.time(int(hours[0:2]), int(hours[2:4]))
            return Hourmin
```

Is it another one that uses floats?

Comment: What do you mean by _null_. Python uses the keyword `None`, do you mean yo the same thing? Or another value such as NaN (from numpy for example)?

Answer (score 0):

Just check for those *null* values, and if `hours` is *null* then return *null*, otherwise continue normally.

Pay attention you have used the term *null*, but since Python uses the term `None`, I cannot infer what is *null* value really is, so in my solution I'm assuming that *null* is actually `None`. If this is not the case, then you can modify it.

```py
def is_null(hours):
    return hours is None

def Format_Hourmin(hours):
    if is_null(hours):
        return None

    if hours == 2400:
            hours = 0
        
    hours = "{0:04d}".format(int(hours))
    Hourmin = datetime.time(int(hours[0:2]), int(hours[2:4]))
    return Hourmin
```

Comment: I'd skip the dedicated `is_null` function in favor of inlining the `hours is None` test; it's not like `is None` is confusing, and `is_null` just requires more checking to verify the meaning.

Comment: @ShadowRanger since in this case the OP's use of the word "null" is a bit unclear, leaving the check in its own function makes the rest of the code more robust.  I'd say it's a good call.  Although I might replace `return None` with `return hours`, since `hours` is already known to have the appropriate value for null.